# Chromium and Firefox Hang on New Chromebook Install of Lubuntu

Tags: firefox, 22.04, snap, chromium, chromebook

I have a new install of lubuntu 22.04.1 on an old Samsung chromebook xe500c13-k01us.  All seems good but chromium and firefox lock system up after a short operation time.  In chromium the hot keys will highlight different things but a hard reboot is needed to get moving.  Both of these browsers are "snap".  Could this be snap or something else?

Comment: "Old" isn't quite as relevant as the actual hardware you have. Chromebooks usually have particularly low end hardware and weren't designed to run a fully fledged OS. Chromium and Firefox are both relatively demanding applications. What CPU does your system have? How much RAM does it have? Are your expectations for performance realistic based on the hardware? Snaps can be slightly more demanding on resources, but not to a drastic level

Comment: You've given few clues as to your hardware; ie. how much RAM do you have. A few cycles ago I had some hardware I wanted to test & needed good RAM, so took some out of the box I'm currently using for that testing... I didn't expect to notice a difference on this box (as I left it with 4GB of RAM), but boy was I wrong! it became slow in the browsers you mention.  It was quickly fixed via increasing swapfile size (Lubuntu uses `calamares` that defaults to a small swapfile that needs increasing on low resource boxes) so have you increased swapfile size?

Comment: You mention *lockup* which shouldn't happen & is likely a very different issue... A *thrashing* system where RAM is limited can cause a system to slow to an "*unusable crawl*" (which isn't a lockup; SysRq commands etc still function without any slowness) so I'd suggest checking if a lockup is actually occurring, or it's just *slow unresponsive* (ie. not locked up, just slow) as is mentioned in the *Enabling RAM Compression* link in [Lubuntu's Swap FAQ](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/swap-and-lubuntu-faq/2591) which was tested on a Chromebook.

Comment: How do I tell the differrence between thrashing and lock up?  Do I just wait?  With the chrome OS, the browser worked OK.

SoC / CPU:  Intel Celeron N3050
Braswell dual core @ 1.6GHz
Memory:  2GB
Storage:  16GB eMMC
Expansion:  MicroSD Card Reader


/swapfile file 512M 342.7M   -2

Based on the link below, would the recommendation be a 4G swapfile?  

https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-create-a-swapfile-in-lubuntu-20-04-20-10/1959

Comment: At Lock up even SysRq commands direct to the kernel won't work (ie. the SysRq command strokes no longer working are clues a kernel crash has occurred), where as with *thrashing* and like issues you'll see changes occur if box is left for 10-90 minutes just very slowly & SysRq and like commands will function (SysRq still quickly, but Ctrl+Alt+F4 etc to switch to text terminal will still be ultra-slow). With 2GB of RAM *swapfile* size is very critical & I bet you don't have enough. 4GB Swap maybe okay (*it depends what you'll do on box; 2GB+ probably*) but you can adjust *swapfile* size ~easily.

Comment: Are you saying that 2.2GB would be a better choice to try than 4GB?

Comment: No, I'm saying only you'll know how you'll use your machine thus can *guesstimate* the most appropriate size for your intended use-case... I was trying to avoid giving a size as it depends on intended usage which I don't know; my only comment was 2GB+ (ram size+) would be my default size; adjusted per intended usage.

Comment: This is on a little laptop that is very portable and used mostly for a portable internet connection.  Any other usage is minimal.  I have a desktop used for other purposes so intended usage is really just a browser with internet connection.